# How do I get quicklisp to load code from the book Practical Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, practical-common-lisp

The [code](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practicals-1.0.3.tar.gz) that accompanies the book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) includes [asdf](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) files.  How do I use [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) to load this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Copy contents of http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practicals-1.0.3.tar.gz to `~/quicklisp/local-projects/`
2. Call `(ql:register-local-projects)` at the REPL
3. Load code from desired chapter (only Chapter 25 tested)

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "id3v2")
To load "id3v2":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    id3v2
; Loading "id3v2"
[package com.gigamonkeys.macro-utilities].........
[package com.gigamonkeys.binary-data].............
[package com.gigamonkeys.pathnames]...............
[package com.gigamonkeys.id3v2]...............
("id3v2")
CL-USER> (in-package "COM.GIGAMONKEYS.ID3V2")
ID3V2> (show-tag-header "/path/to/xyz.mp3")
...
```